# Как с помощью php в wordpress получить товары определённой категории?

Tags: php, wordpress

Как с помощью php отобразить все товары определённой категории (пусть у нашей категории будет название 'pin').

Когда я пишу такой код, то у меня отображаются заголовки всех товаров.

```
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type'  => 'product'
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        while ( $query -> have_posts() ) {
            $query -> the_post();

            the_title();
        }
    ?>
```

А мне надо, чтобы отображались заголовки только товаров из категории 'pin'. Я добавлял 'category_name' => 'pin' в массив переменной args, но у меня в итоге вообще ничего не отображалось.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type'  => 'product',
            'category_name'  => 'pin',
        ));
```

Где `pin` это слаг, а не название.

Comment: Только не `category_name`, а `product_cat`

Comment: @KAGG Design с 'product_cat' оказалось оказалось рабочим. То есть мой вопрос закрыт. А вот решение с 'category_name', увы, нерабочее.

Comment: @KAGGDesign нигде не сказано что речь про WC ;) Но твой ответ я отметил ;)

Comment: Спасибо. А в вопросе сказано: `'post_type' => 'product'`.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Ну это никак не говорит о WC. Возможно даже наоборот - о кастомном типе контента.

Answer (score 1):

Можно делать запрос средствами WooCommerce

```
$products = wc_get_products( [ 'category' => [ 'pin' ] ] );
```